# What is exactly wstatus in wait(&wstatus)

Tags: c, wait

I take a look at wait man page but they only say that status of process is terminated, stop by signal or resume by signal. What if I pass in wstatus = 0. what happend. For example this code make the parent wait for all children to terminate. why status = 0?

```
pid_t wpid;
int status = 0;
while (wpid = wait(&status) > 0);
```

Comment: `while (wpid = wait(&status) > 0);`?!? That's really `while (wpid = ( wait(&status) > 0 ) );` And that's why putting assignments into conditional clauses is a BAD idea.

Comment: When you call `wait(&status)`, it doesn't matter what value was previously in `status`.  It can be 0, or 42, or left uninitialized; the function `wait` never uses it.  So I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: It is an output parameter – the `wait()` function writes into the pointed at variable; it does not read from it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes that's the answer i need. Thank you

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for pointing out. I just copy from other post.

Answer (score 2):

The `status` variable is an output parameter in which is encoded
information about the way the child process terminated.

You can test `if(WIFEXITED(status))` to determine if the termination was normal;
i.e. due to `exit()` or return from `main()`.
If the previous condition is true, then you can obtain the integer
value of the exit code (<=255) with `exit_code=WEXITSTATUS(status)`.

You can also test `if(WIFSIGNALED(status))` to determine if the termination was
due to a signal.
In this case, you can obtain the integer value of the signal (see `kill -L`
for example) with `kill_signal=WTERMSIG(status)`.

If you use `waitpid()`, you can also test other special situations like suspend/resume, but this is less common
(see https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait).

Answer (score 1):

`wait` is system call that makes the `parent process` wait (i.e suspends it) for a *state change* in the `child process`. The *state change* according to the documentation is:

> A state change is considered to be: the child terminated; the child was stopped by a signal; or the child was resumed by a signal.

So the `status` that is passed into `wait`, if not `NULL`, then it will be set to a value that provides info on how the child processe's state had changed.
This value can be inspected for more insight using macros like:

> **WIFEXITED**(status)
>   returns true if the child terminated normally, that is, by calling exit(3) or _exit(2), or by returning from main().
>
> **WEXITSTATUS**(status)
>   returns the exit status of the child. This consists of the least significant 8 bits of the status argument that the child specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument for a return statement in main(). This macro should only be employed if WIFEXITED returned true.
>
> **WIFSIGNALED**(status)
>   returns true if the child process was terminated by a signal.

There are a few more and can be found [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait).

And in your code,

```
wpid = wait(&status)
```

the `wpid` is the `pid` of the child process that has been terminated (which has to be >0)

Comment: The POSIX specification for [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) says: _The `wait()` function obtains status information for process termination from any child process. The `waitpid()` function obtains status information for process termination, and optionally process stop and/or continue, from a specified subset of the child processes._

Comment: The Linux man page at die.net says: _The `wait()` system call suspends execution of the calling process until one of its children terminates._ You have to use `waitpid()` or perhaps `waitid()` to detect other state changes.